# vim-go show sign when struct implements interface

Tags: go, vim, neovim

I'm using [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) plugin with neovim as IDE for go. With the command `:GoImplements` I'm able to see if a struct implements an interface.
Is there a way to show an icon on the left side of the struct which is always shown when a struct implements an interface? The same way like errors are shown. I've seen the same in Goland.

Comment: How useful is it to know that some struct implements *an* (some, any) interface? Don't you want a full list of which interfaces it implements? I'm not sure how a gutter icon or similar would help here, unless you can detect mouseover or something. Not saying it can't be done, or that it's not a good idea, just wondering about implementation.

Comment: For me it is interesting because I can see directly if a struct implements an interface. Otherwise I would have to look at each struct first. 
Another advantage is when I write a struct myself and it should implement an interface I can see directly if I have implemented all functions. Without calling :GoImplements.
I find this function especially useful when reading foreign code to get a quick overview.

Comment: Hm, maybe my point might be better made if I noted that many structs implement `Stringer`. That's probably not the interface you want to know about, though. (Maybe this sort of thing doesn't come up in your code, but I find it happens a lot in mine.)

Comment: I got your point. But I think there is not right or wrong just a question of taste :)